# NTFS symlinks don't work in mounted folders via samba share

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, samba

I have Windows 7 computer and make on NTFS driver folder that I like to share. Inside this folder I've made NTFS symlink from one directory to another. Then I'v shared this folder and mounted as folder under Ubuntu. Linked folders looks empty.

Full description what I've done:

- On Windows server:

  - Created folder "D:\share", inside make folders "share\dev\css" and "share\static\"
  - create symlink with `mklink /D` from "share\dev\css" to "share\static\css"
  - command `dir` inside directory "D:\share\static\css\" shows me all files I expect to see here
  - shared "D:\share\" as "dev-share"
- On Ubuntu (or OSX):

  - mounted "smb://IP/dev-share/" but "static/css" is empty

I think that is Windows share settings problem, so as I dont found answer in Google may be you know how to turn on symlink in shared folders?

Answer (score 2):

in /etc/samba/smb.conf add this to the global section

follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no

then restart samba

sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart

Comment: pete, thank you for replay, but its not Linux samba client problem, samba server this time is Windows server. I need to find smb.conf analog in Windows 7.